# Is printf equivalent to dprintf(STDOUT_FILENO)?

Tags: c, linux, printf

I am learning something about PIPE in Linux, but I met something I can't figure out. I was reading rozmichelle's blog http://www.rozmichelle.com/pipes-forks-dups/#pipelines. The code below is to sort three words that parent process passes on to child process by PIPE.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fds[2];                      // an array that will hold two file descriptors
  pipe(fds);                       // populates fds with two file descriptors
  pid_t pid = fork();              // create child process that is a clone of the parent
  
  if (pid == 0) {                  // if pid == 0, then this is the child process
    dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);    // fds[0] (the read end of pipe) donates its data to file descriptor 0
    close(fds[0]);                 // file descriptor no longer needed in child since stdin is a copy
    close(fds[1]);                 // file descriptor unused in child
    char *argv[] = {(char *)"sort", NULL};   // create argument vector
    if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) exit(0);  // run sort command (exit if something went wrong)
  } 

  // if we reach here, we are in parent process
  close(fds[0]);                 // file descriptor unused in parent
  const char *words[] = {"pear", "peach", "apple"};
  // write input to the writable file descriptor so it can be read in from child:
  size_t numwords = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < numwords; i++) {
    dprintf(fds[1], "%s\n", words[i]); 
  }

  // send EOF so child can continue (child blocks until all input has been processed):
  close(fds[1]); 

  int status;
  pid_t wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // wait for child to finish before exiting
  return wpid == pid && WIFEXITED(status) ? WEXITSTATUS(status) : -1;
}
```

In the code above, the parent process uses `dprintf`, but I wonder if we can redirect parent  process' standard out to PIPE's in. So I tried to write the code below.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fds[2];                      
  pipe(fds);                      
  pid_t pid = fork();              
  
  if (pid == 0) {                  
    dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);    
    close(fds[0]);                 
    close(fds[1]);                 
    char *argv[] = {(char *)"sort", NULL};   
    if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) exit(0);  
  } 

  // if we reach here, we are in parent process
  close(fds[0]);                 
  const char *words[] = {"pear", "peach", "apple"};
  // write input to the writable file descriptor so it can be read in from child:
  size_t numwords = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
  dup2(fds[1],STDOUT_FILENO);//redirect stdout
  close(fds[1]); //fds[1] is not used anymore
  for (size_t i = 0; i < numwords; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[i]); 
  }
  close(STDOUT_FILENO);
  int status;
  pid_t wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0); 
  return wpid == pid && WIFEXITED(status) ? WEXITSTATUS(status) : -1;
}
```

After redrecting, I used `printf`, which in my understanding will output to STDOUT. However, this code print nothing, while the first code print as below:

```
apple
peach
pear
```

I can't figure out why this happen, is there something I understand mistakely?

Comment: Add a `fflush(stdout);` after the loop with the printfs?

Comment: @Shawn, Thank you! That's amazing!

Comment: I would use `fclose(stdout);` instead of `close(STDOUT_FILENO);` to get automatic flushing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to man pages, [dprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) is a POSIX extension, not a standard library function, so it is not equivalent in terms of portability.

As far as their implementation in GLIBC is concerned, both `printf` and `dprintf` call `__vfprintf_internal`, but note that [`dprintf`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iovdprintf.c.html#__vdprintf_internal) does also this `(done != EOF && _IO_do_flush (&tmpfil.file) == EOF)` which suggests flushing the buffer after the write.
[`printf`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/printf.c.html#40), on the other hand, does not.

I'd try fiddling with buffering, i.e. [`setbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf), [`fflush`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) or similar on the stdout and see if that helps.